# React - handle state of value nested in initial object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I am just trying to handle input **state** of tasks which is nested in **initial object**. I want to set the task value to the name in state dataGoal object.

**The initial state look like so:**

[image]

**The render method:**

```js
render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <main className="content">
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

            <div>
              {Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal).map( (key, index) => {
                  return <div key={key}>
                            <label>{this.state.dataGoal[key].name}</label>
                            <p>Index: {index}</p>

                            <div className="input-wrap">

                              {Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal[key].tasks).map( (taskKey) => {
                                  return <div key={`task-wrap-${taskKey}`}>

                                           <p>{taskKey}</p>

                                            <input
                                              type="text"
                                              name="name"
                                              value={this.state.dataGoal[key].tasks[taskKey].name}
                                              onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, key, taskKey)} />

                                        </div>


                              })}

                            </div>
                            <a className="add-link" onClick={(e) => this.appendInput(e, key)}>
                              {"+ ADD ANOTHER TASK"}
                            </a>
                         </div>;
              })}
            </div>

            <div className="input-wrap">
               <input
                 className="primary-btn"
                 type="submit"
                 value="Set my goal!"
                 onClick={this.formReset} />
             </div>
           </form>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**and handleInputChange function:**

```js
  handleInputChange = (e, key, taskKey) => {
    console.log(this.state.dataGoal[key].tasks);
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    const dataGoal = this.state.dataGoal[key].tasks;
    const updatedTask = Object.assign({}, dataGoal[taskKey], { [name]: value });

    this.setState({
      dataGoal: Object.assign({}, dataGoal, { [taskKey]: updatedTask })
    });
  }
```

everything looks like it should work fine but I am just getting an error that it "Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined" in handleInputChange. But if I console.log the tasks it gives me the desired output:

[image]

**Does anyone have a clue please?**

Thank you,
Jakub

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The initial state.dataGoal is set to empty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved this problem by destructing the state like so:**

```js
handleInputChange = (e, key, taskKey) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;

    this.setState({
      dataGoal: {
          ...this.state.dataGoal,
          [key]: {
             ...this.state.dataGoal[key],
             tasks : {
               ...this.state.dataGoal[key].tasks,
               [taskKey] : {
                 ...this.state.dataGoal[key].tasks[taskKey],
                 [name]: value
               }
             }
          }
      }
    });
  }
```